# Delphi - Get Windows' default non-unicode character set

Tags: delphi, character-encoding, non-unicode

I have a Delphi 7 application. I need to be able to get the default Windows character set for non-unicode programs. I know DEFAULT_CHARSET sets it, but I need to know exactly which charset it is, so that I could compare it to other character sets. Is this possible and how?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it's `GetACP`.

Comment: Can you define precisely what you want. Windows character set is imprecise.

Comment: @WarrenP - thank you, that worked for me! Now, what would be the best way to convert the Code page to a TFontCharset? David Hefferman - we are talking about the character set DEFAULT_CHARSET is set to, based on what language is selected in Windows' Regional and Language settings for ["Language for non-Unicode programs"](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/int_pr_select_language_version.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 5):

GetFontData is calling `GetObject` and using `LogFont.lfCharSet` to determine the charset

[GetObject called with HFONT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd144904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) will fill [LogFont](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145037%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
Definition here is

> DEFAULT_CHARSET is set to a value based on the **current system
>   locale**. For example, when the system locale is English (United States), it is set as ANSI_CHARSET.

[GetCPInfoEx with CP_ACP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) delivering  a [CPINFOEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317781%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure will deliver the **system default** Windows ANSI code page.

```
var
 CPInfoEx:TCPInfoEx;
 CD:Cardinal;
 CharsetInfo:TCharSetInfo;
 CSN:String;
begin
 If GetCPInfoEx(CP_ACP,0,CPInfoEx) then
  begin
    CD := CPInfoEx.Codepage;
    if TranslateCharsetInfo(CD,CharsetInfo,TCI_SRCCODEPAGE) then
      begin
      CharsetToIdent(CharsetInfo.ciCharset,CSN);
      Showmessage(CPInfoEx.CodePageName+' - '+IntToStr(CharsetInfo.ciCharset)+' - '+CSN);
     end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: @bummi - I couldn't try this as TCPInfoEx and GetCPInfoEx don't seem to be declared in my Delphi 7 Windows unit. Is there any advantage or difference in using this method as opposed to simply using GetACP (which actually _is_ declared in the Windows unit) as Warren P suggested?

Comment: Should lead to the same result, this link provides information to GetACP http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318070(v=vs.85).aspx following the llink to GetCPInfo leads to a link to GetCPInfoEx

Comment: @jedi It's pretty simple to add the missing declarations.

Answer (score 0):

Here is full example for Delphi 7.

```
unit Main;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  _cpinfoex = record
    MaxCharSize: UINT; { max length (bytes) of a char }
    DefaultChar: array[0..MAX_DEFAULTCHAR - 1] of Byte; { default character }
    LeadByte: array[0..MAX_LEADBYTES - 1] of Byte; { lead byte ranges }
    UnicodeDefaultChar : WCHAR;
    CodePage : UINT;
    CodePageName : array[0..MAX_PATH] of char;
  end;
  TCPInfoEx = _cpinfoex;
  {$EXTERNALSYM CPINFOEX}
  CPINFOEX = _cpinfoex;
  {$EXTERNALSYM GetCPInfoEx}

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure Check;
  public

  end;

  function GetCPInfoEx(CodePage: UINT; dwFlags : DWORD; var lpCPInfoEx: TCPInfoEx): BOOL; stdcall;
  function GetCPInfoEx; external kernel32 name 'GetCPInfoExA';

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Check;
var
 v_CPInfoEx : TCPInfoEx;
 v_CD : Cardinal;
 v_CharsetInfo : TCharSetInfo;
 v_CSN,
 v_CodePageName,
 v_s, v_info : String;
 v_i : Integer;
begin
 If GetCPInfoEx(CP_ACP, 0, v_CPInfoEx) then
  begin
    v_info := 'CodePage: '+IntToStr(v_CPInfoEx.CodePage)+#13;

    v_CodePageName := '';
    v_i := 0;
    repeat
      v_CodePageName := v_CodePageName + v_CPInfoEx.CodePageName[v_i];
      inc(v_i);
    until v_CPInfoEx.CodePageName[v_i] = #0;
    v_info := v_info + 'CodePageName: '+v_CodePageName+#10#13;

    v_info := v_info + 'MaxCharSize: '+IntToStr(v_CPInfoEx.MaxCharSize)+' bytes.'+#13;

    v_s := '';
    for v_i := 0 to MAX_DEFAULTCHAR - 1 do
      v_s := v_s + IntToStr(v_CPInfoEx.DefaultChar[v_i])+' ';
    v_info := v_info + 'DefaultChar: '+v_s+#13;

    v_s := '';
    for v_i := 0 to MAX_LEADBYTES - 1 - 1 do
      v_s := v_s + IntToStr(v_CPInfoEx.LeadByte[v_i])+' ';
    v_info := v_info + 'LeadByte: '+v_s+#13;

    v_info := v_info + 'UnicodeDefaultChar: '+v_CPInfoEx.UnicodeDefaultChar;

    ShowMessage(v_info);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Check;
end;

end.
```