# How can i fix this error on updating Indy 10 on Delphi 2007

Tags: delphi, indy, delphi-2007, indy10

I'm trying to update Indy on my fresh Windows 10 / Delphi 2007 installation. I've download the sources from the official github mirror.

But when i try to compile IndySystem110.bpl, i get lot of errors :

```
[DCC Error] IdGlobal.pas(2926): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'TCPInfoEx'
[DCC Error] IdGlobal.pas(2943): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'GetCPInfoEx'
[DCC Error] IdGlobal.pas(2957): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[DCC Error] IdGlobal.pas(2958): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
[DCC Error] IdGlobal.pas(8471): E2280 Unterminated conditional directive
```

Maybe i download the wrong source ? What should i do ?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps, first two errors are raised because `TCPInfoEx` record is not declared in `Windows.pas` unit of your out of date Delphi. [See this answer to how declare it for your Delphi version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34633419/5581243). What about another errors - they could be linked either with absence of `TCPInfoEx` or with unknown reasons. P.S. Seems it is good time to update Delphi..

Comment: The 1st 4 errors are related to each other. I was not aware that D2007 did not have `GetCPInfoEx()` defined. As for the opening conditional on line 8471, it is closed properly on line 8473. But I see an opening conditional on line 8481 that is not closed properly. I will fix these when I get a chance. I recently did a mass check-in for a lot of code that has been pending for a long time, and I'm finding a few errors made it through (that's what happens when I don't have access to a working compiler at the moment)

Comment: Thank you Remy ! I'll try to download next week then.

Comment: I have checked in fixes now